# Declarative partitioning with Postgres for integer column

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I was reading this article:
https://blog.timescale.com/scaling-partitioning-data-postgresql-10-explained-cd48a712a9a1

the article lifts information directly from here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE

My question is - if we declaratively create a partitioned table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    city_id         int not null,
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY peaktemp;
```

and then let's say we insert into `measurement`, but with a `peaktemp` that is not covered by an existing partition.

Before we insert, do we need to manually create our own partition like so:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement_55 PARTITION OF measurement FOR VALUE 55;
```

..or will Postgres create that table for us if we insert into `measurement` with peaktemp as 55?

Sorry the syntax might be wrong but hopefully the question makes sense.
Basically I want to partition a table by an integer column, one partition for each value of the integer. And I am wondering what is automated and what remains manual in this case?

Comment: It's not automated , at least in Postgres 10 and 11 for range or list partitions .  If corresponding partition doesn't exist, `insert` throws an error.

Comment: @a1ex07 thanks is there a good spot in the docs to look for creating a partition on an integer field?

Comment: Yeah , added as an answer  - quote is too long for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done manually.  From the doc page (already mentioned in the question) 
 - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) -
under

> 5.10.2.1 Example  To use declarative partitioning in this case, use the following steps: ....
>
> 2. Create partitions. Each partition's definition must specify the bounds that correspond to the partitioning method and partition key of
>      the parent. Note that specifying bounds such that the new partition's
>      values will overlap with those in one or more existing partitions will
>      cause an error. Inserting data into the parent table that does not map
>      to one of the existing partitions will cause an error; an appropriate
>      partition must be added manually."

Comment: does you likes the OP?

Comment: any idea why the insert has to be done manually? why can't PG just figure out which table to insert into etc?

Comment: @AlexanderMills .  It's not  insert that has to be done manually.  The corresponding partition must exist before inserting record.  This part (creating new partition if not exists) requires manual step, not insert itself.